# Do I need a lock on a concurrent method that takes in ReadOnlyCollection as a param?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, immutability

Say a method looks like this.

```
Class MyClass
public string ConcatenateList(ReadOnlyCollection<string> aList)
{
  var result = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (string s in aList)
  {
     result.Append(", " + s);
  }
  return result.ToString();
}
```

Here's an example of a caller makeing a read-only list to pass to MyClass.ConcatenateList method.

```
var list = new List<string>(){"hello","world"};
var readOnlyList = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(list);
```

While it is true that the method cannot modify the list, it is required the **caller be able to modify the underlying list** while the method is executing. Also, the **method must be concurrent**.

2 questions:

(1) Given above requirements, is there a race condition in the method? As far as I can see, there is none. ThreadA will never read from or write to ThreadB's StringBuilder, so there's no concurrency issue and thus there is no need for a lock. True?

(2) Will there ever be a case where concurrency might cause the returned string to have unexpected result? One example: ThreadA returns with ",hello,world,howdy" even when "howdy" was added in the midst of execution to the list owned by ThreadB only. Can this happen?

I'm trying to understand, given concurrency, if ConcatenateList() must be a "pure function" i.e. the method is guaranteed that its param "aList" will never be modified (by itself or the caller) during the entirety of method execution?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Answer (score 3):

`ReadOnlyCollection` does not copy the data in the list provided in the constructor into a new collection that only exposes read-only members.  Instead it merely wraps the `IList` provided and only exposes the read-only members of it.

This means that the `ReadOnlyList` is accessing the same memory that is being accessed by the original `List` reference in your code, and proper synchronization needs to be used in order for this to be safe.  In this example, since there is no synchronization, modifications to the underlying list by the caller, while the other thread is accessing the read only list, can cause any number of undefined behaviors.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that even if the original _collection_ were immutable, this wouldn't necessarily guarantee that the individual _items_ were immutable (though I think with String they would be), so that would be something else to watch out for.